# Unable to connect to uploadify using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, uploadify

```
<html>[enter image description here][1]
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
      Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
    
    <?php

$ftp_server = "94.23.x.xxx";
$ftp_username   = "anxxxsdx";
$ftp_password   =  "6Zxxxxx65exx";

// setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$remote_file_path = "/JustForTest".$file;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
        FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";

?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the error message while compiling : Select image to upload: No file chosen
**Couldn't connect to 94.23.x.xxx**

Any inputs I just tried to run this by pasting the entire code on notepad and saving it as upload.php extension.

***I am new to php and uploadify integration. Please help.

I have tried all most all the possible way. Please suggest.

Comment: I have deleted that particular thread, and started a very sorted thread over here.

Comment: If your input's name is `uploadedfile`, then for the variable $_FILES you should change it to this  `$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]`. From where did you exactly take the ["uploadedfile"]["name"] field ?

Comment: Hi @OrisSin not sure what you are saying but I took help from random threads and some PHP tags. If you could share the exact syntax with what I wrote or what is required to correct, would be fantastic.

Moreover I want to randomly upload the from my Local Computer and wants that particular file to get uploaded into the uploadify server.

Comment: _"And here is the error message while compiling : Select image to upload: No file chosen Couldn't connect to 94.23.x.xxx"_ - compiling, what compiling? And where is the first part of the message supposed to come from? The code you have shown only appears to be responsible for the `Couldn't connect to ...` part, there is nothing in what you have shown us, that could produce `Select image to upload: No file chosen ` _before_ that connect error message.

Comment: Sounds more like `Select image to upload: No file chosen` might be what your browser shows for the file upload field, before the user has even made any selection? Well in that case, if you don't select any file to upload with your form to begin with, then what uploaded file are you expecting to process on the server side?

Comment: Hi @CBroe Refer to the attached image. hehe Of course it says to upload the image but beneath that it shows - "cannot connect to....". (How come it is possible that I will not try to upload any data? LOL) and even if you upload any data like Img etc, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do a check on your `$_FILES` variable if you are actually receiving anything from the client side.

I would recommend you also to do one more conditional statement which checks if the tempFile you created, has been moved to your target path. If not, then probably you are facing some issue with your connection to the FTP.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
   $file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
   $tempFile = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];                          
 
   $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/JustForTest". $file;  
   $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/', $targetPath) . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']; 
   ftp_put($conn_id, $targetPath, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_ASCII);
  ftp_close($conn_id);

  if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)){  // string of temporary name file, the destination path of the moved file                    
     echo true; // you can echo something in here to try and see if your code executes until that point
   }else{
    echo false;
   }
     
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oris Sin thanks a ton for the above reply, but does that link to the "Access Issue"? At least my code should be able to connect to the Uploadify server.

Comment: It checks the validity of your input in the POST. As per the connection, I don't have further info on how you are setting it up. If you can share more info as regards the matter, that would be grateful.

Comment: Hi @Oris Sin lemme give a try.